# how to get mpeg file format in opencv

Tags: opencv, video, codec, mpeg

I'm using opencv and its functions to record video in terms of separate  file format in ".mpeg"(instead of .avi). Though I have changed codec and size of the video based on other web reference.Also i installed ffmpeg .but i got same error for every codec variations.

[[OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x314d4950/'PIM1' is not supported with codec id 1 and format 'mpeg / MPEG-1 Systems / MPEG program stream'
[mpeg1video @ 0x1dac700] MPEG1/2 does not support 10/1 fps
Could not open codec 'mpeg1video': Unspecified error]]]

```
\\writeVideo  = new VideoWriter(videoFileName, CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G') , 10, Size(640,480),true);
```

.
.
.
.
        strcat(newVideoFileName, ".mpeg");

I expect the video file in mpeg/mpg format but the actual output it does not displaying record video

Comment: What OS are you using? How/where did you install OpenCV? How/where did you install `ffmpeg`? Did you install `ffmpeg` before or after OpenCV?

Comment: os is ubuntu 16. I installed opencv-3.2https://jeanvitor.com/installing-linux-opencv-eclipse/          after opencv i installed FFMPEg

Comment: I think you need to install `ffmpeg` **before** OpenCV as OpenCV locates all the libraries and things it needs during installation if you do a full build/install. I am suggesting you install OpenCV again now that you have `ffmpeg` installed.

Comment: Is it necessary to install ffmpeg to get format in mpeg

Answer (score 0):

videoFileName sets a file format and CV_FOURCC sets the codec.

If you want .mpeg then use videoFileName = "1.mpeg".

Example:

```
    cv::VideoWriter vw("1.mpeg", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M','P','G','1'), 25, cv::Size(640,480), true);
    if (vw.isOpened())
    {
        cv::Mat rgb(480, 640, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            vw << rgb;
        }
        rgb = cv::Mat(480, 640, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255));
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            vw << rgb;
        }
        rgb = cv::Mat(480, 640, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            vw << rgb;
        }
        vw.release();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout  << "1.mpeg not opened" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I need in mpeg format and in mpeg extension

Comment: Mpeg is only standard container for audio and video (like avi). But it can use different codecs.

Comment: ok.i'll try this one codec can be CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G') or CV_FOURCC('x','2','6','2').

Comment: Try CV_FOURCC('M','P','G','1') or CV_FOURCC('m','p','1','v')

Comment: int codec= capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC,CV_FOURCC('M','P','G','1'));
   frame_width = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
   frame_height = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
                 int fps=capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,10);//    this is the part of the code.

Comment: After changing fourcc:                                                                                  OpenCV:  FFMPEG: tag 0x00000001/'????' is not supported with codec id 46 and format 'mpeg / MPEG-1 Systems / MPEG program stream'
Could not find encoder for codec id 46: Encoder not found
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: cannot link elements
) in CvVideoWriter_GStreame
VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer(filename, fourcc, fps, frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:
error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open

Comment: I added example to answer, it works on Ubuntu 18.04. But used ffmpeg backend for VideoWriter

Comment: I'm creating VideoWriter with mpeg format and write 20 blue frames, 20 margenta frames and 20 red frames. After VideoWriter is closing

Comment: why you use this line Scalar(0, 0, 255))

Comment: cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0) - blue, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255) - margenta, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255) - red